# How to order relationship objects on query execution

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

*The following code is for Flask-SQLAlchemy, but would be quite similar in SQLAlchemy.*

I have two simple classes:

```
class Thread(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String)
    messages = db.relationship('Message', backref='thread', lazy='dynamic')

class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    text = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

I would like to query all Threads and have them ordered by last message created. This is simple:

```
threads = Thread.query.join(Message).order_by(Message.created.desc()).all()
```

Threads is now a correctly ordered list I can iterate. However if I iterate over
`threads[0].messages` then Messages objects are not ordered by Message.created descending.

I can solve this issue while declaring the relationship:

```
messages = relationship('Message', backref='thread', lazy='dynamic',
                                   order_by='Message.created.desc()')
```

However this is something I'd rather not do. I want explicitly set this while declaring my query.

I could also call:

```
threads[0].messages.reverse()
```

..but this is quite inconvenient in Jinja template.

Is there a good solution for setting order_by for joined model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Thread.messages` marked as `lazy='dynamic'`.  This means that after querying for threads, `messages` is a query object, not a list yet.  So iterate over `threads[0].messages.order_by(Message.created.desc())`.